# close a new tab that is opened by a form submit redirect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

Goal is to close a new browser tab that is opened by form submission with `target="_blank"`.

On the page new (unregistered) users can compile a form, the form actually can only be submitted by registered,logged in, users.

As I don't want to stop them, make them register, in part of the form, the user enters their name and email. When they press a submit while not logged in, the info is transferred to a registration form that is the one that gets submitted, registers & auto-logs them in.

I don't want to redirect from the page they are on because then they would need to refill the entire form. So I have the registration/auto log-in happen in a new tab, after which the parent page refreshes (with the user now logged into the site) and the main form (which still has all the info) now gets submitted.

This is the registration form that gets populated by the "main" form and trigger with jQuery `.click()` on its submit button when main form is sent without the user being logged in.

```
form id="registerform1" method="post" action="/?instance=1" name="registerform" target="_blank" >
```

This is the function in my function.php that logs the user in automatically:

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
        wp_set_current_user($user_id);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
            // You can change home_url() to the specific URL,such as 

        wp_redirect( 'http://.mysite.com/somepage/' );
        exit;
    }
    add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
```

The problem is I don't want the new tab to stay open more than a few seconds. `window.close()` is not working. How do I add JS to make the new tab close?

Comment: Why would you open an entirely new tab when you could do it in an `iframe`? You'd have much more control over the `iframe` element, as well.

Comment: @DevlshOne totally the way to go.